# Linq - advanced .OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

```
Foo().OrderBy(x=> x.Name)
```

What if I want the collection to be sorted that way, but exactly one element with Id == (let's say 314) should be always in the beginning, regardless of its name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can sort it on two rounds:

```
Foo().OrderBy(x => x.Id == 314 ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

Maybe this is even simpler (assuming boolean false is sported before boolean true)

```
Foo().OrderBy(x => x.Id != 314).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: Boolean false sorts before true. ILSpy shows that `Boolean.CompareTo` returns 0 if the values are equal, -1 if `this` is false, otherwise 1.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd handle that afterwards at the client, but if you'd like a LINQ way, then I would probably avoid `Concat` - it'll be a more complex query. I'd go for:

```
int id = 314;
var data = Foo().OrderBy(x => x.Id == id ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

```
var foo = Foo();
foo.Where(x => x.id == 314).Union(foo.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
```

Comment: According to MSDN (see link above), this is a better solution than anything involving `Concat` because `Concat` allows duplicates.

Comment: `Single` returns a single object - you can't call `Union` on that.

Comment: This would invoke Foo() twice which isn't always a great idea.

Comment: If it worked (re: Single) I would like this one, except it ends up with two invocations of `Foo()`. Depending on what backs it, that could be expensive.

Comment: @Tim Rogers, @jishi, @sixlettervariables: Good points. I've edited to take those comments into account :-) Sorry about that.

Comment: Union can change the results. The question doesn't say that the source does/doesn't contain duplicates. I would use Concat personally, to be safe. Well, actually I *wouldn't* - but between Union and Concat, I'd use Concat.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: What do you mean, it can change the results? Are you trying to imply it is nondeterministic?

Comment: @Platinum - no, I'm saying that if the original data **had duplicates**, then we should surely preserve them. Union will (very deterministically) remove them. Concat will (very deterministically) not.